# Replacing strings with \ in linux

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I need to replace the occurrence of "badfile 'C:users\username\desktop" with "badfile 'filepath\badfile" on FileA. In other words, replace badfile 'C:users\username\desktop with badfile 'filepath\badfile

I tried the following approach but no effect

```
test=badfile 'C:users\\username\\desktop
test1=badfile 'filepath\\badfile
echo $test
echo $test1
sed -i 's|$test|$test1|g' FileA
```

I need help on how to make this code work or a better approach will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. encapsulate the values your variables with double quotes `"`, to preserve the singe single-quote character in their values.
2. escape the backslash character `\`, as `\\`
3. replace the single quotes `'` in the `sed` command with double quotes `"`, to allow variable substitution. Using single quotes, you're telling it to replace the *string* `$test` with the *string* `$test1`.

You get:

```
test="badfile 'C:users\\\\username\\\\desktop"
test1="badfile 'filepath\\\\badfile"
echo $test
echo $test1
sed -i "s|$test|$test1|g" FileA
```

Answer (score 0):

here it goes

```
#echo $test

badfile 'C:users\username\desktop

#echo $test | sed "s/\(.*\)\'\(.*\)/\2\|\1'/g"| sed 's/|/\\/g'

C:users\username\desktop\badfile '
```